# Show random Splash screen

Tags: ios, random, screen, splash-screen

Is it possible to launch a different splash-screen each time I launch my app ?
Because it seems that the splash-screen HAS to be named Default.png, so it seems that only one splash-screen can be shown.

Thanks,

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In this case, it's most common to show a "branding" company splash screen, and then once the execution gets into your app (`appDidFinish…`) putting up a secondary splash screen with your customized/changing/animated image.

Answer (score 3):

This is not possible. Default.png will always be shown (symbolic links won't work either).

---

It would also be confusing to the user if a different splash screen is shown every time.

Comment: It is not confusing if just a little message is changing (like on MineCraft first page) on the main picture.

Answer (score 0):

NO you cannot do it. Please read the answer to this qestion [Is there any way to save an image an default.png programmatically on the iphone?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1168109/277021)

Answer (score 0):

You could create a black splash screen and then show a random UIImage for xyz seconds at the start of your app.